# JSP Unable to compile when importing java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, jsp, exception

Well the title says it. I couldn't find any answer anywhere. When I import this class in my .jsp file (w/o using it), it throws an excepton saying the class could not be compiled. Am I missing something?

Import: <%@ page import="java.time.LocalDateTime" %>

Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:85)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:415)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Comment: using gradle ? add "repositories { flatDir name: ‘localRepository‘, dirs: ‘lib‘ }"

Comment: If you aren't using Java 8, you need something like [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: Yes I am using Java 8.. I am using the class all over the place in my other classes (like DAO or entity model classes) and it works just fine everywhere except in jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What java version using your server/servlet container?

You should update java version for server also. It's pointing lower version of java.

Comment: web.xml:
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1"
    >
Server: Tomcat 6 (maybe this is the cause?)
However when configuring I did select java 8 (I don't even have java 7 installed, not the jre, not the jdk, nothing), using IntelliJ as IDE.

Comment: Yes, You should change Tomcat version. you should go with Tomcat 7 or 8.

Comment: Yes, thank you, however I found a workaround which fits quite well as a solution to the problem. Thanks for confirming. :)